# Three unnecessary lines in column

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I try to add 2 ArrayList to column, works but not like i want.
Currently i have this code in my app, but this code makes - 3 first rows with maps, and 3 next rows with numbers. I would like to change -  first and second list in first 3 rows. 
I have 3 elements in one and two List.

```
   for(LatLng a : maps)
    {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES('"+a+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    }

    for(String b : numbers)
    {

        String sql2 = "INSERT INTO table1 (column2) VALUES('"+b+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

    }
```

I tried to change it in several ways and always goes wrong.

Edit:
So when i have 3 element in list1 like this:

```
99.9999999, 99.9999999  
99.9999999, 99.9999999  
99.9999999, 99.9999999
```

and 3 element in list2 like this:

```
11  
12  
13
```

It's look like:

```
Column1:                    Column 2:     ID:   
99.9999999, 99.9999999                     1  
99.9999999, 99.9999999                     2  
99.9999999, 99.9999999                     3  
                               11          4  
                               12          5  
                               13          6
```

I want result like this:

```
Column1:                    Column 2:     ID:   
99.9999999, 99.9999999          11         1  
99.9999999, 99.9999999          12         2  
99.9999999, 99.9999999          13         3
```

Comment: are your collumn1 and column2 defined  as nullable in db?

Comment: i have: `null: no`

Comment: check for sql parameter to prevent sql injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: edited post now u see  how table look

Comment: re-edited, the now showed what result I want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about java sintaxis. But if `a` and `b` are arrays you can do something like this.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ 0) {

   String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2) VALUES('"+a[i]+ "', '" +b[i]+ "')";
   stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

}
```

Comment: cant you do something like this in java?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  Your syntax is correct if `a` and `b` are arrays.  But the poster had variables `maps` and `numbers`.  We don't know whether those are Arrays or Lists or something else.  If they are lists, then the syntax is `maps.get(i)`.

Comment: @Enwired But the logic looks good to solve OP question, isnt?

Comment: Please don't promote bad habits by posting sample code that uses dynamic SQL when it would be easy to use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: still I do not understand, so what should I do to get the result?